# How to override the default "async" pipe with a custom pipe in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'd like to do something like this:

```
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { PushPipe } from '@ngrx/component';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Pipe({
    name: 'async'
})
export class AsyncPushPipe<T> extends AsyncPipe {
    constructor(cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private pipe: PushPipe<T>) {
        super(cdRef);
    }

    transform<T>(obj: Observable<T> | Promise<T>): T | null;
    transform<T>(obj: null | undefined): null;
    transform<T>(obj: Observable<T> | Promise<T> | null | undefined): T | null {
        return this.pipe.transform(obj as any);
    }
}
```

I am adding it to my app module but none of the code seems to be executing. PLATFORM_PIPES got deprecated in Angular 2 and this is supposedly the way to override default providers just by adding the code to the app's NgModule.

Any tips?

Note: I know this is an anti-pattern but I'd like to do some measurements before deciding if moving to a push pipe is a good idea.

Comment: just do global replace for pattern `|\s*async` to `| push`

Comment: That's a fair idea but if there is a in-code solution then that would be preferred. Thank you for your suggestion!